# Sending arbitrary commands to redis using ioredis

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis, redisearch

Is it possible to send arbitrary commands to Redis using ioredis for Node JS?

For example, I'm using the new RediSearch module, and want to create an index using the command:

```
FT.CREATE test SCHEMA title TEXT WEIGHT 5.0
```

How would I send this command using ioredis?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will get you there, although not sure about the response encoding:

```
var 
    Redis = require('ioredis'),
    redis = new Redis('redis://:[yourpassword]@127.0.0.1');

redis.sendCommand(
    new Redis.Command(
        'FT.CREATE',
        ['test','SCHEMA','title','TEXT','WEIGHT','5.0'], 
        'utf-8', 
        function(err,value) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(value.toString()); //-> 'OK'
        }
    )
);
```

If you're willing to search to [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis), there is a [pre-built RediSearch plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-redisearch) that supports all the RediSearch commands. (Disclosure: I wrote it)

Comment: Cheers - I'll try this out when I'm back at the office next week. Same with the RediSearch module!

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, these variants will work as well:

```
redis.call('M.CUSTOMCMD', ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'], 
function(err, value) { /* ... */ });

// if you need batch custom/module commands
redis.multi([
  ['call', 'M.CUSTOMCMD', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'],
  ['call', 'M.OTHERCMD', 'arg-a', 'arg-b', 'arg-c', 'arg-d']
])
.exec(function(err, value) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `call` which execute the module.